# Infinite loop in many-to-many relation

Tags: django

I would like to use a ManyToMany relation. I have the following models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name = odels.CharField(max_length=200)
  songs = models.ManyToManyField(Songs)

class Songs(models.Model):
  name = odels.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Now, upon saving a Person instance, I would like to build a many-to-many relation:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        song_instance, created = models.Songs.objects.get_or_create(name = some_name)
        self.songs.add(song_instance)
        super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The problem with the above code is that upon form submit in the admin panel I get error

> 'Person' instance needs to have a primary key value before a
>   many-to-many relationship can be used.

However, if I switch the order as follows:

```
super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
self.songs.add(song_instance)
```

I do have a pk, but i will have to add another call to `self.save()` in order for the songs to be added to the Person instance, and that will cause an infinte loop.

So how can I go forward and make this work? :)

Thanks,
Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to save after adding an item to a ManyToMany relation. That doesn't modify the instance itself - it just adds a row to the (explicit or implicit) intermediate table. (The same is true of a reverse ForeignKey relationship - calling `add` changes the item to be added, not the item being added to.)